# Execute bash script on a remote-linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a bash script lets say `test.sh`. This script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "khaled"
ads2 svcd&
```

This script simply prints my name (just for test purposes) and execute ads-service application in the background. When i run the script on my ubuntu, it works correctly. As a test i checked which programs run on the kernel

[image]

As you see. ads2 runs and has 12319 process-id.

Now what I'm trying to do is to run the script on the ubuntu, however remotely from a windows pc.

Therefore i opened command-line on windows and executed the following command:

```
ssh nvidia@ubuntu ip-address ~/test.sh
```

And i get the following

[image]

As you see the scripts run and prints khaled,however on windows command line and what i want is that the script is executed on the ubuntu. this justify why the line`ads2 svcd&` doe not do anything, neither on windows (which makes sense, since `ads2` is installed on ubuntu) nor on linux.

So how can i execute the script on ubuntu ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It should work as it is.

Comment: Try adding the full path to the ads2 executable

Comment: It *is* running on the remote Linux. The output is piped back over your SSH connection, to be displayed on your terminal. Try adding an `echo $HOSTNAME` or `ls` for example, to prove it's running remotely.

Comment: @NVRM thatnks for the comment. My question is: is the test.sh is executed on the ubuntu or on the windows?

Comment: @slim thanks for the comment. i added ls after printing my name. It didn't print anything execpt "khaled"!

Comment: You may need to `nohup` ads2 as well, unless it already knows to detach and daemonize. Otherwise it may die when it's parent shell does. Not sure if that is the entire problem though.

Comment: @WayneVosberg thanks for the comment. Do you mean to add it before `ads2 svcd&` ?

Comment: @k.jbaili on the ubuntu. This is the shell of your remote. This is remote execution. You just get the text output. Yes, this is extremely powerful. You don't need a big pc but remote machines to get a lot of power. Your script can turn day and night for pennies, for less than you would pay in electricity. Good luck.

Comment: @NVRM. I hope so. However i still wonder why the command `ads2 svcd&` is not executed properly when the script is invoked remotely, however it only works locally on the ubuntu

Comment: @WayneVosberg it returns `./test.sh: line 3: ads2: command not found`. Despite the fact that ads2 svcd& on the ubuntu works locally

Comment: Try `locate ads2` where is the executable. Note the full path. Use the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the full path to start ads2. When using remote SSH your environment variables may be different than in a local shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "khaled"
/home/nvidia/ads2 svcd&
```

Not sure where ads2 is located.
Try the following to locate it on your Ubuntu local shell.

```
command -v ads2
```

You may also need nohup to persist the process beyond the life of the SSH session.

Comment: Thank you man it works. Yes its because the variables. However shall i use nohup before the command like `nohup /home/nvidia/ads2 svcd&` ?

Comment: and can i execute the following: `ssh nvidia@ip-adress /home/nvidia/ads2 svcd&`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the script on the remote server and you want to run this, you would add back ticks,

`ssh user@server './test/file.sh'`

The script's output would be sent to your local machine, as if you ran the command from your local machine.